# Map Reduce for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection in which each object contains details of the user along with the comments user has given on specific products which is given below

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887"),
"value": {
    "UserDetails" : [
                        [
                            {
                                "country" : "CA",
                                "gender" : "M",
                                "age" : "18",
                                "userIdtemp" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
    "comments" :    [
                        {
                            "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc41786df13540e46891"),
                            "comment" : "Hey, what's up?",
                            "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:49.400Z"),
                            "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
                            "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                        },
                        {
                            "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc43786df13540e46893"),
                            "comment" : "Cool",
                            "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:51.004Z"),
                            "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd2786df13540e4688b"),
                            "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                        }
                    ]
    }
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46888"),
"value" : {
     "UserDetails" : [
                        [
                            {
                               "country" : "US",
                               "gender" : "M",
                               "age" : "25",
                               "userIdtemp" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46888")
                            }
                        ]
                ],
     "comments" : [
                    {
                        "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc41786df13540e46892"),
                        "comment" : "Not much",
                        "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:49.475Z"),
                        "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46888")
                    }
                ]
}
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46889"),
    "value" : {
            "UserDetails" : [
                    {
                            "country" : "US",
                            "gender" : "F",
                            "age" : "13",
                            "userIdtemp" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46889")
                    }
            ]
    }
}
```

I have to extract comments separately along with there userDetails with key as productId so i have written map something like following

```
mapCommentsFrom = function(){
if("comments" in this.value)
{
    for(var idx = 0;idx<this.value.comments.length;idx++){
        var key = this.value.comments[idx].productId;
        var value = [{
            commentId: this.value.comments[idx].commentId,
            comment:this.value.comments[idx].comment,
            created:this.value.comments[idx].created,
            productId:this.value.comments[idx].productId,
            userId:this.value.comments[idx].userId,
            country:this.value.UserDetails[0][0].country,
            gender:this.value.UserDetails[0][0].gender,
            age : this.value.UserDetails[0][0].age
        }]

    }
}
emit(key,value);
}

reduceFrom = function(k,values){
return values;
}
```

but where ever the number of comments are more than one i am getting only the last comment along with user details and other's key as well as value is coming null. Something like this

```
{ "_id" : null, "value" : null }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51efcbd2786df13540e4688b"),
    "value" : [
            {
                    "length" : 2,
                    "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc43786df13540e46893"),
                    "comment" : "Cool",
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:51.004Z"),
                    "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd2786df13540e4688b"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887"),
                    "country" : "CA",
                    "gender" : "M",
                    "age" : "18"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
    "value" : [
            {
                    "length" : 1,
                    "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc41786df13540e46892"),
                    "comment" : "Not much",
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:49.475Z"),
                    "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46888"),
                    "country" : "US",
                    "gender" : "M",
                    "age" : "25"
            }
    ]
}
```

Can somebody please help me as to what i am missing?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: you are emitting too late. Your emit is done after the for loop and that causes only the last comment to be emitted. You should emit at the end of the for loop and then in the reduce function, you should iterate over all comments with the same product id and do whatever you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot add comments due to reputation.  But had you considered using the aggregation framework.

The `$unwind` operator will return you an array of sub documents quite easily and it's faster than using map/reduce.

I'm not sure it will exactly do what you're looking for but may help.

Take a look, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 0):

By **far** the easiest is to just use the aggregation framework for this. The aggregation framework allows you to execute operators on data, there is `$match` for doing queries (like `find()`) and various others. See for more information: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/

The aggregation framework also has an `$unwind` function that does exactly what you want. You use it like:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: '$value.comments' },
    { $project: {
        _id: '$value.comments.productId',
        value: 1
    } }
] );
```

On your sample documents, this returns:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
            "value" : {
                "UserDetails" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "country" : "CA",
                            "gender" : "M",
                            "age" : "18",
                            "userIdtemp" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "comments" : {
                    "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc41786df13540e46891"),
                    "comment" : "Hey, what's up?",
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:49.400Z"),
                    "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51efcbd2786df13540e4688b"),
            "value" : {
                "UserDetails" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "country" : "CA",
                            "gender" : "M",
                            "age" : "18",
                            "userIdtemp" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "comments" : {
                    "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc43786df13540e46893"),
                    "comment" : "Cool",
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:51.004Z"),
                    "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd2786df13540e4688b"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46887")
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
            "value" : {
                "UserDetails" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "country" : "US",
                            "gender" : "M",
                            "age" : "25",
                            "userIdtemp" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46888")
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "comments" : {
                    "commentId" : ObjectId("51efcc41786df13540e46892"),
                    "comment" : "Not much",
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-07-24T12:44:49.475Z"),
                    "productId" : ObjectId("51efcbd4786df13540e4688c"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("51efcbc8786df13540e46888")
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks Derick for the reply but as I am new to MongoDB so can you please provide some links which can help me in getting started with Aggregation framework. And also I want to know does MongoDB driver for C# supports it or not?

Comment: I've added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not emitting them in the map function.
Move the emit function inside the for loop.

```
mapCommentsFrom = function(){
if("comments" in this.value){
for(var idx = 0;idx<this.value.comments.length;idx++){
    var key = this.value.comments[idx].productId;
    var value = {
        commentId: this.value.comments[idx].commentId,
        comment:this.value.comments[idx].comment,
        created:this.value.comments[idx].created,
        productId:this.value.comments[idx].productId,
        userId:this.value.comments[idx].userId,
        country:this.value.UserDetails[0][0].country,
        gender:this.value.UserDetails[0][0].gender,
        age : this.value.UserDetails[0][0].age
    }
    emit(key,value);
}
}
}
```

Then you may also need to rewrite your reduce function to something like this

```
reduceFrom = function(k,valueArray){
var returnData = { values : [] } ;
for(var i=0;i<valueArray.length;i++)
    returnData.values.push(valueArray[i]);
return returnData;
```

}